# Analog to Ruby bundler in Scala

Tags: scala, bundler

Are there any analog of Ruby [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) in Scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think SBT assembly is what you are looking for it will create a single jar file which can be used 'standalone' :
http://implicit.ly/sbt-assembly-071
SBT is the 'scala' built tool if you will, it helps a lot managing scala projects: https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki

Answer (score 1):

Look out for [proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).

I don't know your Ruby bundler, but proguard is able to strip down the archive to the needed classes only. Very interesting, easy to use.